# How to return a String value instead of java bean class from a spring controller

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I have a requirement to call the Spring controller based url through angularjs and print the response returned from the Spring controller to browser.
So it's a PoC in which homepage contains a button when user clicks the button it internally calls a function and in that function Spring controller is called.
It's displaying the message when the message is wrapped in **Java Bean Class** and returning the java bean class as it is.

But when I'm returning a direct String value from the controller it is printing **undefined** in browser console.
I'm new to Angular+Spring Integration so is there any way to return direct **String/Integer** obj from the controller.

MyController
-------------------

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/home")
    public ModelAndView showHome() {
        return new ModelAndView("home");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/getMessage",method=RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json")
    public String getMessage() {
        /*Message msg= new Message();
        msg.setMesg("Hello From AngularJS");*/
        return "Hello From AngularJs";
    }

}
```

**Note-** I'm returning a String value directly from the controller instead of **Message** object.

Home.jsp
-------------

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Home| Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href='<c:url value="/main.css"></c:url>'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app= angular.module("myApp",[]);
    app.controller("hello",function($scope,$http){
        $scope.getMessage= function(){
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'getMessage'  /* Tried even with fully qualified url 'http://localhost:8080/AngularJs-Spring-HelloWorld/getMessage' */
                }).then(function successCallback(response){
                    $scope.user= response.data;
                },function errorCallback(response){
                    console.log(response.statusText);
                }); 

        }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="hello">
    <div class="bb">
        <h2 style="color: orange;text-align: center;">Angularjs Spring MVC sample application!!</h2>
        <button style="text-align: center;" ng-click="getMessage()">Greet User</button>
        <p>{{user}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How to return a String value from the controller and display it in browser. Is there any way to return a String value from controller?

Or the returned string value will be treated as a view page name as it treats in a normal spring-mvc application.

Comment: Hi Stone! This is not an AngularJS problem, but a Spring specific one. You're saying that your response `produces="application/json"` but I'm not sure if Spring can cast a String to JSON just like that.

Comment: Could you try with produces = "text/plain" instead of json?

Comment: @Unknown thanks it worked and what are the more possible values i can specify for **produces** attribute

Comment: You can use any of the Media Type from the file. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import GSON jar in you application and change your return statement as follows then you can return a string from spring controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getMessage",method=RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json")
    public String getMessage() {
        /*Message msg= new Message();
        msg.setMesg("Hello From AngularJS");*/
        return new GSON. toJson("Hello From AngularJs");
    }
```

Similarly if there is any type of java bean you want to return you can convert the bean to JSON string and return it as string as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getMessage",method=RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json")
        public String getMessage() {
            Message msg= new Message();
            msg.setMesg("Hello From AngularJS");
            return new GSON.toJson(msg);
        }
```